cannot set properties in undefined setting
Why i am getting cannot set properties of undefined setting (background color) in JavaScript code.
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
let h2 = document.querySelector('h2');
let p = document.querySelector('p');

function changeColor () {
    console.dir(this.innerText);
    this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

btn.addEventListener("click", changeColor());

h1.addEventListener("click", changeColor());

h2.addEventListener("click", changeColor());

p.addEventListener("click", changeColor());



By removing the parentheses () after changeColor, you're passing the function reference itself to addEventListener, rather than executing the function immediately. This should resolve the error you're encountering.
btn.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
h1.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
h2.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
p.addEventListener("click", changeColor);

